# How to align div area to left so its flush with a centered table?

Tags: html, css

My layout so far for the site is as follows:

## HTML

```
<div class="tabArea"> 
    some more code
</div>

<table class="tablesorter">
<tbody>
    some more stuff here
</tbody>
</table>
```

## CSS

```
table.tablesorter{
    margin:0px auto 0px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    width:750px;
    height:400px;
}

div.tabArea {
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:0px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I would align the tabArea div to that it is flush on the left with the centered table. I am using text-align to center. However, the centers the div on the whole page. Moreover, if I align to the left, then it will go all the way to the left. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Are you trying to align it like this: tabArea|tablesorter?

Comment: So you want `.tabArea` to be aligned to the left? Then you can try `float: left;`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `<tr>` and `<td>` tag when working with `<tbody>`, otherwise it "throws" the text out of table. For the **tabArea** to align correctly (to the outer left corner of the table), you'll've to put all of the content in a container. Try this:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="tabArea"> some more code</div>
   <table class="tablesorter">
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>some more stuff here</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

```
.tablesorter {
font-family:sans-serif;
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
background-color: #F5F5F5;
width:750px;
height:400px;
}
#container { margin: 0 auto; width: 750px;}
.tabArea { font-weight:bold; text-align: left;}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/pgxh6r31/

```
<div class="tabArea"> 
    some more code
</div>

<table class="tablesorter">
<tbody>
    <tr>
         <td>
           some more stuff here
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table> 

table.tablesorter{
    margin:0px auto 0px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    width:750px;
    height:400px;
}

div.tabArea {
    width: 750px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:0px;
    position:relative;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table td {
border : 1px solid black;
}
```